# Copy URL with unicode symbols without percent-encoding in Firefox

Tags: firefox-for-android

[Methods](https://superuser.com/a/1255451/107496) used on Desktop version don't work. I have both `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy`=`true` and `network.standard-url.escape-utf8`=`false` and URLs are still encoded.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. While it's perfectly valid for a lot of users my greatest problem is that it's much harder to edit these URLs: any non-ASCII char takes three times more space and really hard to distinguish. Also, I personally dislike URL shorteners because it's much harder to know what you are opening. However I don't think that any other solution is coming any time soon so I'll accept your solution if you post it as answer until anything better is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an [old bug as reported here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271088). I did not find any other bug report that specifically relates to Android for this problem (Edit:OP has created a [feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1637502))

A url shortner such as [Tiny url](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tiny_url/) add-on may be an alternative, till a better solution is found, keeping in mind the [reservations of OP in comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224951/copy-url-with-unicode-symbols-without-percent-encoding-in-firefox#comment292492_224951)

Comment: Created feature request here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1637502